# $(n+1)$-th derivative of an infinitely differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an infinitely differentiable function. Suppose that for some positive integer $n$, $f(0)= f(1)= f^{(1)}(0)= f^{(2)}(0)=...f^{(n)}(0)=0$, where $f^{(i)}(0)$ denotes the $i$-th derivative of $f$ at $0$.

Then which of the following options are true?

(a) $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ is constant in $[0,1]$.

(b) $f^{(n+1)}(x)\neq 0$ for any $x \in[0,1]$.

(c) All the subsequent derivative has at least one zero in $(0,1)$.

(d) $f^{(n+1)}(x)= 0$ for any $x \in[0,1]$.

**My attempt:**
Using Mean value theorem, $\exists x_{0}\in (0,1) $ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x_{0})= 0.$

In the question, does "for any $x \in[0,1]$" mean "$\forall x \in[0,1]$"?

If that is the case, then how to proceed further?

Comment: I agree, "for any $x \in[0,1]$" is ambiguous.  Maybe it means $\forall x \in [0,1]$.  Maybe it means $\exists x \in [0,1]$.  The writer of the question should re-do it.